# Excel sum if formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

In workbook2 I have the following formulas

> a10=IF('[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$5="","",'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$5)  b10=IF('[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$6="","",'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$6) c10=IF('[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$7="","",'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$7) d10=IF('[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$8="","",'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$8) e10=IF('[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$9="","",'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$9) f10=IF('[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$10="","",'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$10)
>   g10=IF('[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$11="","",'[workbook1.xlsx]sheet1'!$N$11)

The values of the referenced cells are formatted as time 13:30

In cell `h10` I am adding/subtracting the values of the referenced cells with the following formula

```
h10=(b10-a10)+(d10-c10)+(f10-e10)+g10
```

But I get an error value if any of the referenced cells are blank. It only works if there is a value in every referenced cell. I would like the formula in `h10` to treat the blank cells as zeros

Example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMVdo.png]

Comment: Then change the True return from `""` to `0`.  If you want to show an empty string for 0 then format it as such `hh:mm;;` which will show a blank for any cell that returns 0.  And you will be able to treat them as 0.

Comment: Related: [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel 2010](//superuser.com/q/515932/150988).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it with

```
=if(<cell>="",0,<cell>)
```

and make it :

```
h10=(if(b10="",0,b10)-if(a10="",0,a10))+(if(d10="",0,d10)-if(c10="",0,c10))+(if(f10="",0,f10)-if(e10="",0,e10))+if(g10="",0,g10)
```

Hope that helps. (: